# API call to email / newsletter

Tags: feature-request, email, api, newsletter

Let's say I have an Stack Exchange API call like this:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?min=3&sort=votes&tagged=algorithm&site=stackoverflow&fromdate=2014-05-30

I'd like to be able to subscribe to receive an email showing me these results (similar to [the filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters)).

Some considerations:

- Allow us to specify dates relative to the current date (preferred), or simply return all results from the previously sent newsletter (i.e. `fromdate` is auto-populated with the date of the previous newsletter)
- Allow specifying frequency, similar to the filters, although I'd like weekly and perhaps monthly options as well (the current options are 15 minutes, 3 hours and 1 day).
- Allow specifying columns to display (I'd specifically like to be able to see the question score and perhaps number of answers)

---

---

After playing around a bit, I managed to write (Java) code to send a very basic mail like this to myself:

[image]

(I can post the code somewhere if someone is interested)

If there's some existing code (Java, C++ or C# preferably) out there that does something like this and gives some prettier results, I'd appreciate being pointed to it.

(But I'd still like the above feature request implemented)