# It is possible set the weekly newspaper with filters?

Tags: support, feed, newsletter

After read this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121634/271772) about what is the weekly newsletter and who composes them, I'm interested in subscribe in some of them, however, the newspaper doesn't seem to have filters for receive specific content.

For example: I would like receive a weekly newspaper about questions with [c#] tag added on them.

A more expanded example could be:

I would like to receive a weekly newspaper with:

> - Q&A with [**bicycles**] from Skeptics.StackExchange
> - Q&A with [**catholicism**] from Christianity.StackExchange
> - Q&A with [**yu-gi-oh**] from BoardGames.StackExchange

**it is possible set the weekly newspaper with filters?**

---

I found a [posible duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234890/api-call-to-email-newsletter) (which include the use of the Stack Exchange API and more filters).

Comment: This is almost possible with filters, except of the max interval being "every day" (not weekly).

Comment: @nicael, even better :) all that matters _personally_ is receive newsletter with filter based on tags and across the Stack Exchange sites. I know that some tags aren't use most of the time, but the matters to me here is the newspaper in my inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way here is to use the [stackexchange.com filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new).

You can add the "rules" to your filter, each of them picks the questions from the site(s) and with the tag you select, though the max interval "daily", not weekly. For example, here's how you add the first rule.

> [image]

Here's how it looks when everything's done:

> [image]

Then you name your filter and enter your email (by default it's the one tied to your login provider), and "save changes".