# Is there a way to filter questions from all Stack Exchanges sites from showing in the Hot-Network tab/page?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Instead of using the "hot network questions", is there an alternative that shows different questions from across all SE sites?

I'm asking this because (*AFAIK*), the hot-network tab/page is special - due to the selected questions there were calculated by some criterias and, instead of trying to copy/paste [this code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232424/666066) for remove certain pages from the hot-network tab *or* suggest changes for allow/deny certain pages from appearing in the HN-tab/page, I ask:

Is there a way to choose randomly questions from all Stack Exchanges sites?

---

A way to do this is just enter to the desired page and check the main page, but, I would like to avoid doing that *(I'll reserve my thoughts about it)* and have the randomly choosen questions - as the hot-network feature shows the selected questions.

By writing this question, I do remember (*but I don't have the links, though*) that previously another users asked about removing certain sites and it was another questions about removing other sites.

It wouldn't matter (*for me at least*) that the choosen questions were answered or created months or years ago. I think that maybe there is a (`or a few`) cookie(s) that shows which pages I had visited (*while logged in*) and this could be useful for determine the initial criteria for get and pick questions from the visited sites.

it might considered a duplicated of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84389/666066) - but I really hope it don't. If HN wasnt *so* restricted, I think we could have some interesting questions - maybe a Custom Hot Network? - as the feed currently works and how it shows in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273132/it-is-possible-set-the-weekly-newspaper-with-filters?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C1.3560) that would be a good way to manage the selectable content from across SE sites.

---

Comment: Happy new one! btw, [randomness](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-44b43c0a66383c4c2353bdf87cb6929b) is an illusion ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix :) since english is not my native language, it was the first work I could think of. If you have any better word(s) for improve this questions, please, feel free to do so - that's how I can learn too :)

Comment: I'm kind of confused as to what you want here. Is your main issue that not every site appears on the HNQ list? Or is your issue that the questions that appear there aren't "random"? Or both?

Comment: Besides the HNQ's I'm not aware of any 'list' consisting of random Q's from the countless sites of SE, but you could easily write some script that randomly scuffles together various Q's..

Comment: @Rubiksmoose it is the first one: `my main issue that not every site appears on the HNQ` and I would like to select which one site(s) I don't want view questions.

Comment: there's no filter for the user where you could 'black-list' certain SE-sites from the HNQ's AFAIK

Comment: @iLuvLogix perhaps I would think in writing a script of some sort. Thanks. I want it avoid it since I used to check certain questions and I don't know if IT staff/company will comply to me by checking browser history of other control by making requests to pages - even if they're have ok content - i.e. SFW.

Comment: If you don't want certain SE-sites in your browsers history you just don't visit them while at work ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix and that's a shame, IMHO about not have such filter :( -it's a preference user's issue. If feeds has so, why not HN? - it might be becasue thos are two entirely different features, though :)

Comment: @iLuvLogix I don't visit Movies or related, I mostly visit MSE, MSO, Code Golfing and programming related sites. Trust me. Just, I don't want to those (non-programming or interesting) questions appears ehen I'm at work.

Comment: Personally, I would rephrase the title of your question to reflect what you actually want - a filter for the HNQ's.. Maybe have a look [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=filter+hnq) as well..